# How do I set up Unity for Eclipse?

Tags: android, unity, eclipse

I want to use Unity on Android. How can I integrate Unity with Eclipse?

I searched this site and various forums, but found nothing useful.

Comment: A Google search gives me this: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/71607-Integrating-Unity-and-Eclipse Is this something you've tried and had trouble getting it to work? You should also know that you don't *need* to integrate Unity with E\clipse to create Android games in Unity. So you may want to do some more research on how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution depends upon why you'd want to use Eclipse. If you want to use it for Script editing, you can do that via `Edit->Preferences->External` tools. However you'll be able to use it just as a text editor for C# (I am not aware if you can get syntax highlighting etc. feature for C# in eclipse or not), but for UnityScript you can use it as a full IDE.

If you just want to use an Eclipse Android project, then you can export the unity project as `Google Android Project` from `build settings`.